# Basic Authentication is not more working while reading mail from Outlook Inbox

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, office365, exchange-server, office365api

There was a legacy application running behind the scenes to pull new mails from a mailbox to database. The code looks like this

```cs
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                 
exchangeService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail@domain.com","mailpassword", "");
PropertySet ItemPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
ItemPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
ItemView itemView = new ItemView(10);
itemView.PropertySet = ItemPropertySet;

FindItemsResults<Item> Emails = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
                    new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter[]{
                    new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false)
                    }),
                    itemView);
```

This code was working fine But in last few days i was getting error while execute FindItems

```
11/10/2022 03:55:00 - ERROR WITH INBOUND EMAIL TASK TASK: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 831
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 724
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute() in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\MultiResponseServiceRequest.cs:line 157
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 832
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 937
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName parentFolderName, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 990
```

I came to see the official announcememnt from Mirosoft about Deprecation of Basic Authentication (Basic Auth) in Exchange Online

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/basic-auth-deprecation-exchange-online

So how can we update this code to read the emails again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can we update this code to read the emails again?

You have the following options:

1. If you need more time to update your code, you can [request a one-time re-enablement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437). This will re-active basic authentication until December 2022.
2. Rewrite your application to use OAuth instead of Basic Authentication. You can find Microsoft's official step-by step instructions here, including sample code:

   - [Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth)
3. Do note, though, that EWS [will not get feature updates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/ba-p/608055?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-6771), so you might want to use this opportunity to migrate your application to MS Graph:

   - [Use the Outlook mail REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)